# Python - Usar Threads em janelas para Vários eventos

Tags: python

Após Eu clicar o Botão a janela para de responder até que o som acabe, e oque eu queria que ele continuasse a responder após clicar no botão

````
import winsound
b=winsound.Beep
class janela:
    def __init__(self, janela):

        self.frame=Frame(janela)
        self.frame.pack()

        janela.resizable(width=True, height=True)
        janela.config(bg='gray')
        janela.title('PIIIIIII')
        Canvas(janela, width=600, height=680, bg='BLACK').pack()


        fonte=('Comic Sans MS','14','bold')
        self.botao=Button(self.frame, text='Pi',
                            command=(self.tocar), font=fonte,
                            fg='red', bg='yellow')
        self.botao.pack(side=LEFT)

        
        self.botao1=Button(self.frame, text='Pi2',
                            command=(self.toca2), font=fonte,
                            fg='red', bg='grey')
        self.botao1.pack(side=LEFT)
    def tocar (self):
        b(1000,1000)

    def toca2 (self):
        b(2000, 1000)


jan1=Tk()
janela(jan1)
jan1.mainloop()```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que pesquisei isso é normal do `winsound.Beep`, no `winsound.PlaySound` temos o `winsound.SND_ASYNC`, o que permitiria executar sem travar (creio eu), mas é para arquivos ou sons do sistema operacional (somente Windows, como é o nome da biblioteca, winsound):

- 'SystemAsterisk'
- 'SystemExclamation'
- 'SystemExit'
- 'SystemHand'
- 'SystemQuestion'

Ou então apontar para um arquivo de som existente.

Nesses casos é possível adicionar a flag [`SND_ASYNC`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winsound.html#winsound.SND_ASYNC), se usar somente `winsound.SND_ALIAS` ele também irá congelar até que o som termine.

Mas como provavelmente não usar `PlaySound` e sim o `.Beep` você poderá usar [`threading.Thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html):

```
from winsound import Beep
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import *

...

def tocar(self):
    Thread(target=self.executarBeep, args=[1000, 1000]).start()


def tocar2(self):
    Thread(target=self.executarBeep, args=[2000, 1000]).start()


def executarBeep(self, frequency, duration):
    Beep(frequency, duration)
```

Se você quiser que o som toque até o fim acaso ocorra um duplo clique ou o usuário tente clicar várias vezes basta criar uma variavel para checar quando começa e termina o Beep, liberando ao final, algo como:

```
class janela:
    executando = False

    ...

    def executarBeep(self, frequency, duration):
        if not self.executando:
            self.executando = True

            Beep(frequency, duration)

            self.executando = False
```

Comment: tudo certo, obrigado.